# get ICMPv6 header from IPv6 packet

Tags: c++, c, unix, ipv6, icmp

Hi i'm stuck on getting ICMPv6 header from IPv6 packet.

```
        size = sizeof(sockaddr_in6);
        if ((lenght = recvfrom(socd, buffer, BUFSIZE, 0, (sockaddr *)&receiveSockAddr, &size)) < 0) {
          cerr << "recvfrom error" << endl;
        }

        ip = (ip6_hdr *) buffer;

        cout << "Payload length: " << ip->ip6_ctlun.ip6_un1.ip6_un1_plen << endl;
        cout << "Payload length ntohs: " << ntohs(ip->ip6_ctlun.ip6_un1.ip6_un1_plen) << endl;

        //icmpRec = (icmp6_hdr *) (buffer + ???offset???);
```

I need find out how to set the offset. Only way I know is to get payload length and then the: **packet length - payload length = my offset**. But in **ip->ip6_ctlun.ip6_un1.ip6_un1_plen** are some weird numbers.

From the code above im receiving:

```
Payload length: 25332
Payload length ntohs: 62562
```

after sending ICMP6_ECHO_REQUEST to ipv6.google.com

But if I look in wireshark the Payload length is 8 bytes. How to correctly decode the payload number from **uint16_t** to correct decimal number **8**? And how get the whole size of IPv6 packet to calculate the offset? Why IPv6 haven't IHL as IPv4? This very complicate the work aroud IPv6 I think.

Comment: yes: socd = socket(AF_INET6, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_ICMPV6)

Comment: Can you please check the return value of recv_from. It tells how many bytes are actually read. We need to ensure we are reading the entire header.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be the issue though it was a little hard for me to digest.

Appearently, the IPv6 header is automatically cropped off when recvfrom() is used.

**Quote**

Outgoing packets automatically have an IPv6 header prepended to them
(based on the destination address).  *Incoming packets on the socket are
received with the IPv6 header and any extension headers removed.*

[ipv6 man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man4/icmp6.4.html)

So basically your buffer starts from data and the bytes you are offsetting contain some random  higher layer data.

Comment: Well the man page is of ICMPv6 so it appears on raw sockets too, though i must say i don't seem to imagine why

Comment: No problem - this was really valuable for me too as i didn't suspect it to be the cause